# How to send a POST request with nested Dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I search 100s of posts on StackOverflow but can't find any correct answer can anyone help me to solve this mystery.

```
let param : [String : Any]= [
    "ServiceReqID" : 1,
    "WebUsersID" : customerID,
    "FirstName" : userName,
    "LastName" : "",
    "Company" : self.profileValues.customerCompanyName,
    "City" : self.profileValues.customerCityName,
    "Email" : self.profileValues.customerEmail,
    "ContactNo" : self.profileValues.customerContactNumber,
    "Country" : "Pakistan",
    "PackageChange" : 0,
    "AddressChange" : 0,
    "TelInternetVAS" : 0,
    "Others" : 0,
    "Comments" : comments,
    "CSAFNO" : self.profileValues.customerCSAFNo,
    "SecondaryContactNo" : "",
    "CustomerTicket" : [
        "RequestID" : requestID,
        "TaskID" : taskID,
        "Description" : comments,
        "TicketTypeID" : 3,
        "CustomerID" : customerID,
        "PriorityID" : 3,
        "CustomerTPPID" : TTPIDArray
    ]
]
```

with this code ony first model is sent to server and secound model pass with blanck values

```
func postserviceRequestFeedback (
    url : String,
    parameter : [String : Any],
    tiket : HTTPHeaders
)
{
    Alamofire.request (
        url,
        method : .post,
        parameters : parameter,
        headers : tiket
    )
    .responseJSON { (response) in     if response.result.isSuccess{    } }
```

please help me.

Comment: " ony first model is sent to server and secound model pass with blanck values" What second model? Could you clarify exactly?

Comment: "CustomerTicket" is a second model like nested json.
["RequestID" : requestID , "TaskID" : taskID , 
"Description" : comments ,
"TicketTypeID" : 3 ,
"CustomerID" : customerID , 
"PriorityID" : 3 ,
"CustomerTPPID" : TTPIDArray ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all,
I solve This problem.
Here is the step by step solution to this question.
1)

```
 Alamofire.request(url, method : .post , parameters : parameter , encoding : JSONEncoding.default, headers : tiket ).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess{
          let responseJoson : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            print(responseJoson)
         }
```

encoding is very important here. Don't skip this.
Step 2)

```
 func apiCall(){
  let customerTckt:[String:Any] = ["RequestID" : requestID ,
"TaskID" : taskID ,
"Description" : comments ,
"TicketTypeID" : 3 ,
"CustomerID" : customerID ,
"PriorityID" : 3 ,
"CustomerTPPID" : TTPIDArray ]

let param : [String : Any] = ["ServiceReqID" : 1 ,
                              "WebUsersID" : customerID,
                              "FirstName" : userName,
                              "LastName" : "" ,
                           "Company":self.profileValues.customerCompanyName ,
                              "City" : self.profileValues.customerCityName ,
                              "Email" : self.profileValues.customerEmail ,
                              "ContactNo" : self.profileValues.customerContactNumber ,
                              "Country" : "Pakistan" ,
                              "PackageChange" : 0 ,
                              "AddressChange" : 0,
                              "TelInternetVAS" : 0 ,
                              "Others" : 0 ,
                              "Comments" : comments ,
                              "CSAFNO" : self.profileValues.customerCSAFNo,
                              "SecondaryContactNo" : "" ,
                              "CustomerTicket" :customerTckt]
    let userToken: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "bearer \(accessToken)",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]
   postserviceRequestFeedback(url: postRequestFeedbackUrl, parameter: param , tiket: userToken)
   }
```

Don't skip  "Content-Type" to application/json

Answer (score 1):

You can use in this way

```
    let customerTckt:[String:Any] = ["RequestID" : requestID ,
    "TaskID" : taskID ,
    "Description" : comments ,
    "TicketTypeID" : 3 ,
    "CustomerID" : customerID ,
    "PriorityID" : 3 ,
    "CustomerTPPID" : TTPIDArray ]

    let param : [String : Any] = ["ServiceReqID" : 1 ,
                                  "WebUsersID" : customerID,
                                  "FirstName" : userName,
                                  "LastName" : "" ,
                               "Company":self.profileValues.customerCompanyName ,
                                  "City" : self.profileValues.customerCityName ,
                                  "Email" : self.profileValues.customerEmail ,
                                  "ContactNo" : self.profileValues.customerContactNumber ,
                                  "Country" : "Pakistan" ,
                                  "PackageChange" : 0 ,
                                  "AddressChange" : 0,
                                  "TelInternetVAS" : 0 ,
                                  "Others" : 0 ,
                                  "Comments" : comments ,
                                  "CSAFNO" : self.profileValues.customerCSAFNo,
                                  "SecondaryContactNo" : "" ,
                                  "CustomerTicket" :customerTckt]


func postserviceRequestFeedback(url : String , parameter : [String : Any] , tiket : tiket ){
Alamofire.request(url, method : .post , parameters : parameter , headers : 
HTTPHeaders).responseJSON { (response) in
    if response.result.isSuccess{}}
```

Comment: showing this error
{
  "Error" : true,
  "Message" : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
}

Comment: Did u set headers

Comment: yes i send header
let userToken: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "bearer \(accessToken)",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]

Comment: showing this error on the link you provided
{
  "Error" : true,
  "Message" : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
}

Comment: after trying updated code it shows success message but ticket id = 0 that's the problem feedback parameters are posted but custom ticket parameters are not posted.
{
  "Error" : false,
  "TicketID" : 0,
  "FeedBackID" : 237119,
  "Message" : "Success"
}

Comment: after trying updated code it shows success message but ticket id = 0 that's the problem feedback parameters are posted but custom ticket parameters are not posted. { "Error" : false, "TicketID" : 0, "FeedBackID" : 237119, "Message" : "Success" }

Comment: Have you checked by debugging ?

Comment: these 7 values not posted to server